# Classic Regression Assumptions

Tags: regression

The main thing I want to know is should we always obey the Linear Regression classic assumptions rules ? I mean its seemingly common in Finance era such that the results are not satisfying the Assumptions .
is it common or acceptable ?
is there any alternative assumptions for such situation ?
( for example we can say we almost have Normality of errors using QQ-plot or sometimes we can say we have constant variance in residuals but can not say it is satisfying the assumptions)

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Perhaps you can say how you define the classical assumptions of linear regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main concern with violating assumptions is that it may unduly affect Type I and II error rates. Basically, our results are more likely to be erroneous if we are ignoring assumptions. For a purely statistical view, it's bad practice and and a mis-use of the test. There are alternative "robust" methods that can be used when assumptions are violated.

Introduction to Robust Estimation and Hypothesis Testing, 5th Edition by Wilcox is my favorite for discussing this topic in-depth.

Comment: Yes Sure thanks , 
in the aspect of data modeling (Financial Specifically) the things we should care about the more robust and suitable models can have some intersections in intuition and practice with Classic Regression assumption( Bias and Variance Trade-off for example ) .
at this point of view , what do you think about a Linear model with a very good MAPE or RRMSE with some violations in assumptions ?

Comment: @user398615 ultimately, the trade off on the statistical "proper-ness" of a test and the end goals of the project are a subjective problem for stakeholders to decide. Yes, an assumption violation may not be great statistically, but if a model serves the users needs well then it may be viable. For example, many robust methods are quite a bit more difficult to explain to a layman audience - so it might be simpler to explain classic parametric test instead. Or, in finance, you might was to create a model purely on really good accuracy - even if the underlying assumptions aren't great.

Comment: Yes I'm totally agree , 
actually in the case of prediction ( for example Price prediction ) we see lots of papers which predict the price with a very good metrics results and even better than high-order models like LSTM without really caring about to be accept by classic assumption tests , at the end the main problem is choosing between the candidates , and linear regression can be a good candidate .

Answer (score 0):

In finance, linear regression assumptions are frequently broken. While departures from assumptions, such as non-normality or heteroscedasticity, are widespread, alternatives include transformations, robust regression, or specialized models such as autoregressive approaches. While working with real-world financial data, analysts need to be aware of these variations and use suitable methods such as quantile regression or time series models.

Example:
Autocorrelation in financial time series may be handled using Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average (ARIMA) models, which account for the temporal character of stock movements.